# Mouse/Keyboard (possibly USB in general) not working after BIOS update

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, mouse

I just installed version 8 of the BIOS of the Gigabyte ga-ma790xt-ud4p motherboard. After rebooting, my Razer Diamondback mouse and Razer Lycosa keyboard refused to work.

I didn't have the time to check anything else. What should I try? Resetting CMOS by removing the battery? Anything else maybe?

Comment: Clearing the cmos by removinf and replacing the battery didn't help

Comment: P/S2 keyboard isn't working either.

Comment: Downloading Hiren's Boot CD, to see if input works under that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to solve it.
I left the battery out for an extended time. When rebooting, I got a screen asking me if I wanted to load the last known good settings. First I accepted this, same problem. I then selected the default settings, and it worked.